# activity gets killed in android, how to keep this activity active?

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity

I'm developing an application in cordova/phonegap and it is about tracking a person his gps location and therefore the app needs to be active for a long time

I can keep the application active as long as it is in memory but when you have opened so many applications that android needs more ram space it still kills the application

I know services exist in android but I just cant tell how to use them in combination with a phonegap app

Is there a way to keep the activity of my app in front of the activity stack so it doesnt get killed or can i write a native service that restarts my application when it gets killed (with thesame state as it got when it got killed)

**More detailed description of the problem**
ok as requested a more detailed description of the problem

I have a cordova application (html + javascripts)
in a the application i use navigator.watchposition() which gets called when the gps location changes
i then do some logic and store the data in a websql database (on the device itself), as far as i know this database is only accesible from within a webview

now the point of this application is that it you start it at the morning and stop it in the evening (for example lets say say active for 10 hours from start to finish) you dont need to see the application, and the screen doesnt need to be on

I got the stay active part working for when android never ran out of memory

So what I need to do to get to my problem is start the application -> press the home button -> start about 10 different application (to simulate normal use of a phone), the number 10 can vary on different phones with different ram sizes -> after opening enough other applications my phone will run out of ram memory so then android kills some apps and eventually will kill my app.

This is not good for our application at it tracks time at a location and needs to do this fairly accurately

**-------**

anyway thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to do that. It's against the principles of Android. Instead you should, as you already suggested yourself, use a service to track the GPS location.

Comment: but i dont know how thats the problem i can write the service in java which handles it but my application runs in a webview (-> cordova) and  in the webview it can store the data in a websql database (and apply some filtering on the gps data) but the native service cant reach the websql database as far as i know

Comment: You should definitely use a Service. The solution is probably to locally store the GPS data until the user navigates back to the Activity. You should probably post a more specific description of this problem.

Comment: my reputation isnt high enough to paste something this long as i am about to in a reply so heres a link to pastebin with a more detials description http://pastebin.com/QzGhze5W

Comment: @bavodaniels consider editing your question and adding the detail from the pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem.

In android, activity life cycle can only changed by system, when the activity not on the top, it will easy to be killed by system, so next time you come into your app , it will start from onCreate function on main.java.

If you want make something work background , use service will more appropriate.